# Why ContextClassLoader returns path with exclamation character?

Tags: java, resources, path, web, classloader

I try to open file in jar in WEB-INF/lib with

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
 URL url=classLoader.getResource(myconfig);
```

In debugger I can see:

```
jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/lib/myjarresource.jar! 
 /conf/configuration.xml
```

Why in file path is "!"  ?
I think for this reason application cannot open this file.
How to receive correct path?
Thanks.

Comment: So, if your application cannot open the file - how does the stacktrace look like?

Answer (score 10):

It means whatever comes after the `!` is *inside* the JAR file.

In case of `myjarresource.jar!/conf/configuration.xml`, open up `myjarresource.jar` using a compression utility such as 7-zip and you will see that it contains `conf/configuration.xml`.

Comment: Yes, because there is no physical file in that location. You'll have to use JAR API if you want to read the contents of a JAR file. Or, set your JAR file in classpath and you will be directly be able to read `conf/configuration.xml`.

Answer (score 7):

In the [JarURLConnection javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) , the syntax of a JAR URL is described:

*The syntax of a JAR URL is: jar:!/{entry}*

So '!' indicates that you 'enter' the java archive.

Edit:
I believe that you cannot do `File file=new File(url.toURI())` because of the ":" which appears twice in the generated URI and is not compliant with the [URI specifications](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)(chapter 2.2 and 3) therefore this is rejected in the File ctor.

Comment: If files are within a jar, how to load all the files in a folder.