# Spring boot not finding files in resources folder even when using the resource loading in code instead of file location

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line, jar, filenotfoundexception

I am using the google's common IO, library to read the files in my resources folder of Spring boot app. its working perfectly fine in the IntelliJ, but when I am running this from the command line, My app is picking the `application.yml` present in the same `resources` folder but not picking other files in the same folder.

I've checked that files are present in the jar file, as shown below

```
unzip -l my.jar | grep ".json"

 983  04-14-2022 16:16   BOOT-INF/classes/abc.json
 423  04-14-2022 16:16   BOOT-INF/classes/xyz.json
```

But App is throwing following File not found exception, with the same location.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> file:/Users/amit/code/so-search/target/my.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/abc.json
> (No such file or directory)

This is how I am reading the files in my code.

```
public static FileReader getFileReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(Resources.getResource(fileName).getFile());
        return new FileReader(file);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but isn't the meaning of a `!` in the path, that it is trying to open a zip/jar archive? In the exception you sent, it seems like it is trying to open `classes` as a zip archive (`classes!`). Yet in the console output you sent it looks like it's just a normal folder. Actually yeah, it seems so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9530575/4541480. Don't exactly know why the library is returning such a path, but maybe that's the cause for it not working?

Comment: @Nicofisi , yeah its weird, gone through multiple articles but they didn't help :(,  have done same thing million times but not in sprint boot, did same in DW

Comment: hope this can answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869428/classpath-resource-not-found-when-running-as-jar
basically you should read from an input stream instead from directly the file in the resource folder

Comment: The double `!` is weird, but the more fundamental issue is that the `!` syntax has no meaning outside of a `jar` URL.  Calling `getFile()` doesn’t magically turn the resource URL (which would have been a `jar` URL) into a file URL - it just returns the path component of the URL (plus the query string if there is one), which isn’t going to make  sense if treated as a file name.

Comment: @Johannes, thanks a lot, your link helped fixed me the issue

Comment: @Johannes, let me know if you want to write a answer, would be helpful for others